# Second level submenu CSS

Tags: css

I was hoping if you can help me with my little problem. I am just updating one of my developers style sheets. I am a beginner in CSS so I am having difficulties adding the  second level submenu in it.
Here's the link [DEMO PAGE](http://jsfiddle.net/6t3BQ/)

This is my HTML

```
 <div id="sidebar"><a href="#" class="visible-phone"><i class="icon icon-home">    </i>Dashboard</a><ul style="display: block;">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-signal"></i> <span>Charts &amp; graphs</span></a> </li>

    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> <span>Tables</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon icon-fullscreen"></i> <span>Full width</span></a></li>

    <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-th-list"></i> <span>API</span> <span class="label label-important">4</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">boom</a>
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">% of National Roads Paved</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Regional Profiles</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS

```
/* Top user navigation */
#sidebar{ width:100%; background:#252125;  position:absolute; clear:both; top:62px;}
#sidebar > ul{ margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%; display:block; z-index:999;} 

/*Border right sidebar */
    #sidebar > ul > li { list-style-type:none; float:left; display:block; margin:0px; border-right:1px solid #464652; position:relative; padding:10px; cursor:pointer} 
/*Border right */

#sidebar > ul > li a{ padding:12px 0;}
#sidebar > ul > li:hover ul { display:block;} 
/*#sidebar > ul > li:hover { background-color:#41bedd;} */

/*On hover menu */
#sidebar > ul > li:hover { background-color:#464652;}
/*On hover menu */
#sidebar > ul > li:hover a{ background:none;}
/*Modules color */
#sidebar > ul li ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; display:none; z-index:999;  position:absolute; left:0px; top:40px;  background:#464652; min-width:200px;} 
/*Modules color */
#sidebar > ul li ul li { list-style-type:none; margin:0px; font-size:12px;line-height:30px;  } 
#sidebar > ul li ul li a { display:block; padding:5px 10px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; } 
/*Modules color on hover */
#sidebar > ul li ul li:hover a{ background-color:#5A5A69;} 
/*Modules color  on hover*/
#sidebar > ul li span { cursor:pointer; margin:0px 2px 0 5px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; font-size:11px; }
#sidebar > ul li a i{ background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png"); margin-top:4px; vertical-align: top;}
```

I know this post has been posted from different threads. I really cant understand them. Hope you understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a heads up--CSS only fly-out menus aren't the best in terms of both usability and accessibility--especially when you're talking more than one level deep. You may want to consider sprinkling a little JS into the mix.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll be trying that out later, but as for now I want it that way and I want an answer for my question.

Comment: @DA. Meh. Everybody uses them. THE WORLD SHALL ADAPT TO MEEEEEE! :P What will JS do for you anyway? The best I can think of to do is use semantically correct elements (`<nav>`) and stuff.

Comment: @bjb568 touch support, keyboard support, proper delays to allow slower mouse movements, ability to traverse from trigger to menu diagonally, etc.

Comment: Guys,... May I interrupt? I am still waiting for my answer here... Can you provide me?

Comment: @user3242683 when you post a question to this site, expect comments. They may not always be exactly what you want, but that's sometimes how it is. As for your question, what, exactly, are you having problems with? Which part of this isn't working for you? Can you put the code into a JSFiddle for us so we can play a bit with it?

Comment: @DA. Yes, of course. Those are little tweaks and fixes, the menu is still made out of CSS.

Comment: @bjb568 certainly the menu relies on CSS, but I wouldn't call those other things 'tweaks and fixes'...they are very integral to the overall user experience of the menu. God is in the detail! :)

Comment: I will say, however...maybe CSS3 transitions can carry a bit of the load that JS normally would handle. I'd have to ponder on that for a bit...

Comment: @DA. HTML is the content of the menu. CSS make it uh… a menu. JS is final touches. (fix for mobile bug, make it JS-interactable, etc.)

Comment: @bjb568 we may be debating semantics, but, HTML is the content (the menu itself). CSS is how it looks and is laid out. JS is the interaction, accessibility, and responsiveness part. Granted, as CSS has matured, it's added a bit of interaction skills, but it's not a complete package by any means. I'd never consider JS an 'extra' in this case, but a member of the core team.

Comment: @DA. Ok. Whatever you call it, it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your sample HTML, you don't have any `li`s in your tertiary level. Put some in there.

As for your CSS, it's presently set up to handle the showing and hiding of UL's below the top level one on hover. We need to get more specific so that it excludes the 3rd level--as well as then get more specific to and add a second level hover style.

Where you have this:

```
#sidebar > ul > li:hover ul { display:block;}
```

Change it to this:

```
#sidebar > ul > li:hover > ul { display:block;}
```

The first will show ALL child ULs of the LI on hover. The latter will show only the direct child of the LI on hover.

Now we need to add a trigger for the 3rd level:

```
#sidebar > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul { display:block; top: 0; left: 200px}
```

While we're at it, we included a new set of positioning so that it appears to the right of the current hover rather than below (which would cover up the second level navigation.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wS9t3/

Comment: Thanks DA, We are almost there Sir. Last question, which is not included in my post. How will I be able to align the sub menu contents horizontally? Because when I hover it to the second sub menu its contents appears on the first sub menu,.. why is that? Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/wS9t3/2/ I am hoping you can help me further for this thanks.

Comment: Ah...that's because it is positioned absolutely...therefore, each tertiary menu is going to be in that same spot. Are you able to modify the HTML at all?

Comment: Thanks dude, now I get it. Just added this position:relative;